# Accessing Dictionary Elements from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a column of dictionaries like this:

```py
id                            element
 1  {'Colour': 'Grey', 'Brand': 'AB'}
 2   {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Brand': 'B'}
 3   {'Colour': 'Red', 'Brand': 'AH'}
```

And I want to create new columns from those dictionaries, like this:

```py
id                            element  colour  brand
 1  {'Colour': 'Grey', 'Brand': 'AB'}    Grey     AB
 2   {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Brand': 'B'}    Blue      B
 3   {'Colour': 'Red', 'Brand': 'AH'}     Red     AH
```

I have done the following but it's not working:

```py
def whatever(row):
    tmp_d = {}
    for d in row.values:
        for k in d.keys():
            if k in tmp_d.keys():
                tmp_d[k] += 1
            else:
                tmp_d[k] = 1
    return tmp_d
    

new_df.colour = df.groupby('element')'element'].apply(whatever).unstack().fillna(0)
```

Data:

```
data = {'id': [1, 2, 3],
 'element': ["{'Colour': 'Grey', 'Brand': 'AB'}",
  "{'Colour': 'Blue', 'Brand': 'B'}",
  "{'Colour': 'Red', 'Brand': 'AH'}"]}
```

Comment: A couple things: first, I'm not sure Pandas will even let you assign using dot syntax, but either way, use `new_df["colour"]` to create a the `"colour"` column of your DataFrame (I'm pretty sure you should've gotten a warning about that). Second, if you're applying a function row-wise on a DataFrame, use `axis=1` in the `.apply()` call.

Comment: Also, try to explain *what the problem is*, not just say "it's not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can convert the strings to dict objects. Then you can also use `str.get` method to get values under a specific key:

```
import ast
df['element'] = df['element'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = df.assign(**{key: df['element'].str.get(key) for key in ('Colour','Brand')})
```

Output:

```
   id                            element Colour Brand
0   1  {'Colour': 'Grey', 'Brand': 'AB'}   Grey    AB
1   2   {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Brand': 'B'}   Blue     B
2   3   {'Colour': 'Red', 'Brand': 'AH'}    Red    AH
```

Comment: all the NaN is coming

Comment: create two new column colour and brand. But all are Nan values

Comment: @NikitaAgarwal glad it worked. please upvote the answer too if it was helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.element))
```

Output:

```
   id                            element Colour Brand
0   1  {'Colour': 'Grey', 'Brand': 'AB'}   Grey    AB
1   2   {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Brand': 'B'}   Blue     B
2   3   {'Colour': 'Red', 'Brand': 'AH'}    Red    AH
```

EDIT: since your `element` column is actually comprised of strings that look like dictionaries, you'll need to convert them to real dictionaries first:

```py
import ast

df["element"] = df["element"].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# Solution
new_df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.element))
```

Then you can use my solution.

Comment: Nothing is appearing from that code. sorry

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do you actually have a column of dictionaries, or are they *strings that look like dictionaries?*

Comment: create a new cloumn(with '0') with same content like column name 'element'

Comment: Then you do not have dictionaries, you have strings that look like dictionaries.

Comment: Ok. Then how to access that part